# What is "non-simple applied first-order functional calculus" (60's set theory)

Tags: notation, set-theory, large-cardinals

Azriel Lévy says in his 1960 paper Axiom Schemata of Strong Infinity in Axiomatic Set Theory, that the $\sf{ZF}$ set theory is formalized with a finite number of axioms in "non-simple applied first-order functional calculus". While this obviously refers to what we today call second-order logic, I am curious what precisely does it mean. I have tried to google the phrase with zero results, Lévy's 1979 textbook doesn't say a word about it either.

What was the reference set theory text book in the late 50's or early 60's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *functional calculus of first-order* is FOL.

For a mathematical logic textbook of early '60s, see:

- Alonzo Church, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=KJbKCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA281) (1956), page 281:

> We shall speak of the *pure functional calculus of first order with equality* if the primitive symbols include all propositional and functional variables and no functional constants except $I$ [the binary functional letter $I(x,x)$ for *equality*]; an *applied functional calculus of first order with equality* if there are other functional constants in addition to $I$ [like $\in$ for *set theory*]; a *simple applied functional calculus of first order with equality* 
>   if there are other functional constants in addition to $I$ and no functional 
>   variables.

For a set theory textbook, ref [2] in Levy's paper, see:

- Abraham Adolf Fraenkel & Yehoshua Bar-Hillel, [Foundations of Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=dBZMAAAAMAAJ) (1958): see footnote 3, page 28, with refernce to Church.

---

The difference seems to be in the *axiom of subset*; instead of the now "standard" formulation where the condition "specifying" those $z \in x$ such that ... is expressed through an open statement $\varphi(z)$, with $z$ free, as in Fraenkel & Bar-Hillel, the condition is expressed by Levy through a *functional variable* $p(z)$.

In the first case, we have an *axiom schema*, while in the second we have a formula.

The functional variable is not quantified (this is why the underlying logic is not FOL), but the logic has a substitution rule (see Church, page 218).

Comment: Thank you very much! But one last thing is unclear to me: he claims to have "a formulation of the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory by a finite number of axioms" in said calculus (page 1, last paragraph). How can that be FOL?

Comment: @mikulas - it seems to me (but I've have not read the paper) that he uses three *axioms* instead of *axiom schemata*, because they are formulated with the two *functional* variables $p(z)$ (unary) and $p(x,y)$ (binary). They are single formulae: of course, he needs the substitution rule which allows him to replace e.g. $p(z)$ with $\varphi(z)$ when needed.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, again.